# Secure login system - using sessions?

Tags: authentication, php, session-management

I'm looking for a secure way to let users login on my website. Currently, I've always used a session system, like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (validPass() || isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
    } else {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
            $_SESSION['userId'] = $the_id;
        }
        // User is logged in
    }
} else {
    // Show a login form
}
?>
```

Is this the secure way, or are there better systems? What should I look out for?

Comment: I hope this question includes enough information and isn't too broad. If otherwise, please ask more info / specification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more secure way? Use https along with this. There are two vulnerabilities here:

- When the user logs in, the password that is sent over can be easily read by anyone snooping on your connection. This can't happen on an https connection.
- If a user is already logged in, someone snooping on your connection can just copy over the session cookies. In HTTPS, cookies are transmitted securely, so there isn't much of an issue.

You may also want to log the user IP address and not let them switch, though this may get annoying (for a user like me who is behind a university proxy with rotating external IPs, I'll never be able to log in).

A final observation: Don't use GET for the log out bit.. Try not to use GET for anything which triggers a change -- it's fine for navigation, but not for anything which will lead to something changing on the server (a logout, or anything that writes to a database). See [the prescribed usage of GET and POST for more details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).

If you implement the above, then also make sure that the referrer of a POST request is your site and not some other site. (This, along with the above, will help prevent [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks).

To prevent [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking), disable framing via javascript and the `X-Frame-Options: deny` header.

Comment: Regarding "use POST" - this will not protect against CSRF attacks, at all. Malicious sites can just as easily send POST requests (hidden forms and iframes).

Comment: @JoelL: That's not csrf, that's clickjacking. And it can be prevented by disallowing framing.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not really accurate. Clickjacking  would imply embedding the site in frame, and tricking the user to make actions in that frame. A hidden POST request doesn't require any user interaction.

Comment: @JoelL: Hmm, you're right. For some reason I assumed that POST from another website would not use the session cookies.  I'll edit then.

Comment: Cool. You should also add "…and the X-Frame-Options: deny header" to your last sentence. The header is now supported by all/most modern browsers, so JS shouldn't even be needed for that, soon.

Answer (score 1):

Just to enhance the check method try to add some things about user secure login.
Try to use force cast with (int) in order to avoid any case that the attacker could be use to pass any malicious string and a not empty check also.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) && (!empty($_SESSION['userId'])) {
  $user_id= (int)$_SESSION['userId'];
} else {
  $user_id=0;
}

echo 'Test: '.$user_id;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to answer by Manishearth , I would also recommend the following :

1. Set cookies to be HttpOnly and Secure
   Always write secure ( To make sure that its only readable by HTTPS enabled site) and HttpOnly (To make sure that its not accessible through Script : Can be dangerous if XSS comes up on your site)
2. Enable front end headers like Content Security Policy, Strict-Transport-Policy.